# combine class instance into another instance in python?

Tags: python, join, instance, persistent, chain

I am in designing one "jigsaw puzzle" like tool to manage different water pipe like parts combination for fun.

1. I have different single parts type with different purpose(cooler, heater, purifier...)
2. Those parts with different interfaces size can be connected with each other (1/4 inch. 1/6 inch ....)

I want those parts can be stored in database and can be combined into a total new parts combination(randomly or purposely), but still can be considering as a function-able part.

Here is the initial thinking

```
class MetaInfo():
    def __init__(self, name, intype,outtype,shape,serialno):
        this.name = name
        this.intype = intype
        this.outtype = outtype
        this.shape = shape
        this.sn = serialno


def parts():
    def __init__(self, meta):
        this.meta = meta

def linkwith(self, part):
    if part.meta.shape == this.meta.shape: 
    # make it simple, logical here is just same shape can be connected each other 
        return ???         # a new parts combination 
    else:
        raise Error 

m1 = MetaInfo("cooler", "hotwater", "coldwater", "1/4 inch round", "SN:11111" )
m2 = MetaInfo("heater", "coldwater", "hotwater", "1/4 inch round", "SN:22222" )
m3 = MetaInfo("purifier", "coldwater", "hotwater", "1/6 inch round", "SN:33333" )


a = parts(m1)
b = parts(m2)
c = parts(m3)
```

Here is what I need your help:

1. how to save m1, m2, m3 as a list which can persistent in a human readable database, next time only change that database itself I can add meta?
2. how to chain different parts as a new combination? Such as

   ```
   e = a.linkwith(b)
   d = c.linkwith(a)
   ```

   and store it in that database as well?
3. can I make a long chain, make a new parts instance , such as

   ```
   f = c.linkwith(a,b,d,e)
   ```

and findout easily which part is incapable to link in this chain, here part c with different size?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a relational database.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, thanks, but may not exactly, since database may SQL language related need to be well designed and heavy, here I just need a simple and dry solution how can easily chain different class instance and store them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got bored. It's very rough but it works. If you take this far enough, you will want to use a database; but I understand wanting to use a human readable format.

```
from copy import copy
import csv

class Part_Base(object):
    pass

class MultiPart_Base(list):
    pass

class part_meta(type):
    part_names = {}
    parts      = []
    def __init__(cls, cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict):
        super(part_meta, cls).__init__(cls_name, cls_bases, cls_dict)
        if(not Part_Base in cls_bases):
            part_meta.part_names[cls_name] = cls

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name = kwargs.get("name", "")
        if(part_meta.part_names.has_key(name) and not (self is part_meta.part_names[name])):
            obj = part_meta.part_names[name].__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            obj = None
            if(not part_meta.part_names.has_key(self.__name__)):
                new_class = part_meta(name, (Generic_Part,), {})
                globals()[name] = new_class
                obj = new_class(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                obj = super(part_meta, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not obj in part_meta.parts:
            part_meta.parts.append(obj)
        return obj

    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        all_fields = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x | set(y.fields), cls.parts, set([])))
        with open("parts.csv", "w") as file_h:
            writer = csv.DictWriter\
            (
                file_h,
                all_fields,
                restval        = "",
                extrasaction   = "ignore",
                dialect        = "excel",
                lineterminator = "\n",

            )
            writer.writeheader()
            for part in cls.parts:
                writer.writerow({field : getattr(part, field) for field in part.fields})

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        with open("parts.csv", "r") as file_h:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file_h)
            for row in reader:
                Part(**row)

class Part(Part_Base):
    __metaclass__ = part_meta
    fields        = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
        self.fields += kwargs.keys()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s>" % self.description

    @property
    def description(self):           
        return "%s: %s %s %s %s" % (self.name, self.intype, self.outtype, self.shape, self.serialno)

    def linkwith(self, *parts):
        return Generic_MultiPart(self, *parts)

class Generic_Part(Part):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["name"] = self.__class__.__name__
        super(Generic_Part, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Generic_MultiPart(MultiPart_Base):
    def __init__(self, *parts):
        super(Generic_MultiPart, self).__init__()
        if len(parts) >= 2:
            self.shape = parts[0].shape
            self.linkwith(*parts)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Not enough parts")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<MultiPart: %s>" % super(Generic_MultiPart, self).__repr__()

    def linkwith(self, *parts):
        for part in parts:
            if part.shape == self.shape:
                if isinstance(part, Part):
                    self.append(part)
                elif isinstance(part, MultiPart_Base):
                    self.extend(part)
            else:
                raise ValueError("Incompatible parts")
        return self

class cooler(Generic_Part):
    intype  = "hotwater"
    outtype = "coldwater"
    fields  = ["intype", "outtype"]

class heater(Generic_Part):
    intype  = "coldwater"
    outtype = "hotwater"
    fields  = ["intype", "outtype"]

def make_some_parts():
    some_parts = \
    [
        # This is actually a cooler object
        # The metaclass uses the cooler class from above
        # to create the object
        Part
        (
            name     = "cooler",
            shape    = "1/4 inch round",
            serialno = "SN:11111"
        ),
        # Using the heater class directly
        heater
        (
            shape    = "1/4 inch round",
            serialno = "SN:22222"
        ),
        Part
        (
            name     = "purifier",
            intype   = "coldwater",
            outtype  = "hotwater",
            shape    = "1/6 inch round",
            serialno = "SN:33333"
        ),
        Part
        (
            name     = "carbon_filter",
            intype   = "coldwater",
            outtype  = "coldwater",
            shape    = "1/4 inch round",
            serialno = "SN:33333"
        )
    ]

    useless_part = some_parts[0].linkwith(some_parts[1])
    print useless_part
    filter_part  = copy(useless_part).linkwith(some_parts[3])
    print filter_part

    part_meta.save()

def load_some_parts():
    part_meta.load()
    print part_meta.parts
```

You can manually edit `parts.csv` (in Excel or other) and it will make the parts described.
The save/restore functionality hasn't been extended to MultiParts; you can do that.

Comment: many thanks for your sample code, I need sometime to some time to read it and give you feedback.